# ML Model Overfits if input data is normalized

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, resnet

#### Please help me understand why my model overfits if my input data is normalized to [-0.5. 0.5] whereas it does not overfit otherwise.

I am solving a regression ML problem trying to detect location of 4 key points on images. To do that I import pretrained `ResNet 50` and replace its top layer with the following architecture:

- Flattening layer right after ResNet
- Fully Connected (dense) layer with 256 nodes followed by LeakyRelu activation and Batch Normalization
- Another Fully Connected layer with 128 nodes also followed by LeakyRelu and Batch Normalization
- Last Fully connected layer (with 8 nodes) which give me 8 coordinates (4 Xs and 4 Ys) of 4 key points.

Since I stick with **Keras** framework, I use `ImageDataGenerator` to produce flow of data (images). Since output of my model (8 numbers: 2 coordinates for each out of 4 key points) normalized to [-0.5, 0.5] range, I decided that input to my model (images) should also be in this range and therefore normalized it to the same range using `preprocessing_function` in Keras' `ImageDataGenerator`.

Problem came out right after I started model training. I have frozen entire ResNet (training = False) with the goal in mind to first move gradients of the top layers to the proper degree and only then unfreeze a half of ResNet and finetune the model. When training with ResNet frozen, **I noticed that my model suffers from overfitting right after a couple of epochs**. Surprisingly, it happens even though my dataset is quite decent in size (25k images) and Batch Normalization is employed.

What's even more surprising, **the problem completely disappears if I move away from input normalization to [-0.5, 0.5] and go with image preprocessing** using `tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input`. This preprocessing method DOES NOT normalize image data and surprisingly to me leads to proper model training without any overfitting.

I tried to use *Dropout* with different probabilities, *L2 regularization*. Also tried to *reduce complexity* of my model by reducing the number of top layers and the number of nodes in each top layer. I did play with *learning rate* and *batch size*. **Nothing really helped if my input data is normalized** and I have no idea why this happens.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: when VGG is employed instead of ResNet everything seems to work well!

I really want to figure out why this happens.

---

**UPD:** the problem was caused by 2 reasons:
- batch normalization layers within ResNet didn't work properly when frozen
- image preprocessing for ResNet should be done using Z-score

After two fixes mentioned above, everything seems to work well!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like by default it will not scale samples with mode="caffe" according to this -https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~python/tf/keras/applications/resnet50/preprocess_input/
Why don't you try both mode="tf" and scale in range between -1 and 1 and compare outcomes?
Other than that, I assume that seeing of your code will help to understand your situation better and answer your question.

Comment: @StepanNovikov, you were right, thanks for letting me know. Looks like proper image preprocessing was a part of a solution. I also noticed that if I unfreeze batch normalization layers within ResNet before training of my model, the behaviour of training also improves. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning the Solution below for the benefit of the community.

Problem is resolved by making the changes mentioned below:

1. `Batch Normalization layers` within `ResNet` didn't work properly when frozen. So, `Batch Normalization Layers` within `ResNet` should be `unfreezed`, before Training the Model.
2. Image Preprocessing (Normalization) for ResNet should be done using `Z-score`, instead of `preprocessing_function` in Keras' `ImageDataGenerator`